# Is there a way to navigate to random unanswered questions?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes, I want to just pop on MSE and try to answer an unanswered question. But I find it somewhat unhelpful sifting through the questions in the "pre-filtered" order(s).

I would love to have a button that presents a randomly-selected unanswered question (cf. the "random" link on OEIS, or the "I Feel Lucky" Google hit-link); even better if it observes other filters (*e.g.,* "My Tags").

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I occasionally do this by picking questions with my tags, no answers, and posted on a random day. [This bookmarklet](http://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/#random-noanswer) does the job: to use it, drag the link in bold to your browser's bookmark bar.

It's possible to show just one question on that page by adding `&pagesize=1` to the URL; but this has side effect of setting page size to 1 *everywhere* on the site, until you change it back. So I'd rather not do that. It's easy enough to look at the top question only, or maybe glance at the top three to find something interesting there.

The bookmarklet works on any Stack Exchange site; it just has to be executed when you are already on that site.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!